# How to preserve children when using cloneElement

Tags: reactjs

newComponent props.children is null after using React.cloneElement. Is there a way to preserve the children?

https://codesandbox.io/s/crazy-cherry-tfh2o?file=/src/App.js:0-301

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const component = <div>Testing</div>;
  console.log(component);
  const newComponent = React.cloneElement(
    component,
    { person_id: 12345 },
    null
  );
  console.log(newComponent);
  return newComponent;
}
```

Comment: You're passing in null. Remove it, and newComponent props.children is now "Testing".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you just need to delete the `, null` part, is optional

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const component = <div>Testing</div>;
  console.log(component);
  const newComponent = React.cloneElement(
    component,
    { person_id: 12345 }
  );
  console.log(newComponent);
  return component;
}
```

Comment: writting null you are deleting the children

Answer (score 1):

The `children` argument of [`React.cloneElement`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#cloneelement) is optional. You can just leave it out to preserve the existing children.

```
const newComponent = React.cloneElement(
  component,
  { person_id: 12345 }
);
```